# Using RocketScript without Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, performance, cloudflare, rocketscript

Don't know how to explain it exactly.

I would like to use the rocketscript.js used by cloudflare on my site, without using cloudflare. Like simply including the main script and changing all tags through php to rocketscript ones.

Any suggestion would be appreciated! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare's RocketLoader essentially is asynchronous loading of Javascript; the script itself is kind of useless without the backend components that utilise it.

However; HTTP/2.0 (which CloudFlare support) offers a far more performance, it's a standard which means you can activate it regardless of whichever web property you are on.

Comment: so i can't have my own standalone version of it? instead of using cloudflare?